# First landing page is not populating from SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure

I've developed a site in Visual Studio and after deploying to Azure the first landing page does not populate the DataTable. After clicking any link all the SQL queries and DataTables & GridViews work fine.

The problem did not exist until I deployed to Azure.

Home.aspx content...

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlFeatured" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="width:100%; ">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:250px;">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" style="width:300px; height:300px;" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "Images/ProductImages/" + Eval("IMAGE") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <h5 class="text-center" ><strong>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="Label1" style="color:#782b42;" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "ProductDetail.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("NAME") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                            </strong></h5>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        $<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRICE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

CodeFile:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        dlFeatured.DataSource = DataAccess.selectQuery("SELECT TOP 6 * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE FEATURED = 1 ORDER BY NEWID()");
        dlFeatured.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I have no idea where to even start. The site is live at https://wekeafurniture20190329101320.azurewebsites.net

Comment: @Ken Hall The first step when confronting unexpected behavior, is almost always to determine precisely what is actually happening. Log your app's behavior, just like you would when debugging locally. Azure has tools for viewing those application logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Application service does not recognize the "Set As Start Page" setting in the Visual Studio project.

I had to get to the App Service resource, click on Application Settings, the modify the default documents setting.